# If the rows form an orthonormal basis, the columns form an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that if the rows of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ form an orthonormal basis, then its columns do as well.

What I tried is: let the rows of $A$ be $\vec{a}_1, \vec{a}_2, \ldots, \vec{a}_n$. If I dot $\vec{a}_i$ with $\vec{a}_j$, I get $1$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise, so $AA^T = I$. I think this implies that $A^T$ is invertible with inverse $A$: though I'm not sure how to prove that $A$ is also a right inverse, the matrix is $n \times n$, so a left inverse should be two-sided. If this is the case, then $A^T A = I$. So the columns of $A$ are also orthonormal and therefore a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Another thing I considered is that row rank is equal to column rank, so that would imply that the columns are linearly independent. I'm not sure where the orthonormal conditions come out of that, however.

Comment: Yes, that works. It's a general fact that if a square matrix has either a left or a right inverse then that matrix is its two-sided inverse.